# Intercept STDERR from my process in Java

Tags: java, logging, stderr

I have a Java application with a bunch of classes that print error information to STDERR using `System.err.println("Message here.");` I would like to intercept each line, add the class name and a timestamp, and *then* print to STDERR- without changing the code within the classes themselves.

I realize that I could replace the call to `System.err.println()` with a logger, but I'm trying not to create a dependency on a logger framework (nor do I want to start injecting third party dependencies into these particular classes).

Another suggestion that I've seen on other SE answers is to use some sort of shell scripting- this would work for injecting the timestamp, but it wouldn't be able to tell which class had generated the error.

I'll probably have to break down and inject a logger, but before I do I wanted to see if there were alternatives that wouldn't mess with my existing classes.

Comment: "I'm trying not to create a dependency on a logger framework" Use Java.util.logging. It's pretty good these days.

Comment: `System.setErr` with your own subclass of `PrintStream` ?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 That could work, but is there a way to tell which class is calling it?

Comment: `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getClass().various`